# twitter api tweet id to url

Tags: url, twitter

When I post using Twitter API, its result was like this:

```
Dump => object(stdClass)#55 (2) {
  ["meta"] => object(stdClass)#54 (2) {
    ["status"] => int(201)
    ["msg"] => string(7) "Created"
  }
  ["response"] => object(stdClass)#66 (1) {
    ["id"] => float(86321727668)
  }
}
```

We can see that the twitter has response the success API CREATE POST ACTION with an ID.
As you can see the ID is **86321727668**

My Question is how to change this ID to be a working url

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses the following URL structure for a user's single tweets:
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/status/[id]

So you would need to pull in the user's screen name, and then construct a URL based off that.

In JavaScript:

```
var url = '//twitter.com' + userID + '/status/' + tweetID;
```